# PDF Error reading a content stream

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, postscript

I'm working on capturing postscript calls to `show` and storing the currentfont and font size to output in pdf Text objects.

[PDF file](https://gist.github.com/luser-dr00g/7489c7a84234283e16ce66f702725db4/raw/791aff76fc8357e75dbeaa120ae16d19f92d852b/pd0.pdf)
[Input Postscript Program](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.lang.postscript/F8OgPOPXwN8/discussion)

But `identify` is giving me an error:

```
$ identify pd0.pdf
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

pd0.pdf[0] PBM 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel Gray 61KB 0.000u 0:00.000
pd0.pdf[1] PBM 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel Gray 61KB 0.000u 0:00.000
pd0.pdf[2] PBM 612x792 612x792+0+0 16-bit Bilevel Gray 61KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And ghostscript's output isn't giving me the detail I need to understand the problem:

```
$ gsnd -dPDFDEBUG pd0.pdf
GPL Ghostscript 9.18 (2015-10-05)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
<<
/Root 1 0 R
/Size 12 >>
%Resolving: [1 0]
<<
/Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
%Resolving: [2 0]
<<
/Kids [
3 0 R
6 0 R
9 0 R
]
/Type /Pages /Count 3 >>
endobj
%Resolving: [3 0]
<<
/Parent 2 0 R
/Contents [
5 0 R
]
/MediaBox [
0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0 ]
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/F1 4 0 R
>>
/ProcSet [
/PDF /Text ]
>>
/Type /Page >>
endobj
%Resolving: [6 0]
<<
/Parent 2 0 R
/Contents [
8 0 R
]
/MediaBox [
0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0 ]
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/F2 7 0 R
>>
/ProcSet [
/PDF /Text ]
>>
/Type /Page >>
endobj
%Resolving: [9 0]
<<
/Parent 2 0 R
/Contents [
11 0 R
]
/MediaBox [
0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0 ]
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/F3 10 0 R
>>
/ProcSet [
/PDF /Text ]
>>
/Type /Page >>
endobj
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
Processing pages 1 through 3.
Page 1
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [5 0]
<<
/Length 15660 >>
stream
%FilePosition: 471
endobj
BT
F1
10.0 Tf
%Resolving: [4 0]
<<
/Type /Font /SubType /Type1 /BaseFont /Palatino-Roman >>
endobj
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
Page 2
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [6 0]
%Resolving: [6 0]
%Resolving: [6 0]
%Resolving: [6 0]
%Resolving: [6 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [8 0]
<<
/Length 31667 >>
stream
%FilePosition: 16474
endobj
BT
F2
10.0 Tf
%Resolving: [7 0]
<<
/Type /Font /SubType /Type1 /BaseFont /Palatino-Roman >>
endobj
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.
Page 3
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [3 0]
%Resolving: [6 0]
%Resolving: [9 0]
%Resolving: [9 0]
%Resolving: [9 0]
%Resolving: [9 0]
%Resolving: [9 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [1 0]
%Resolving: [2 0]
%Resolving: [11 0]
<<
/Length 8335 >>
stream
%FilePosition: 48487
endobj
BT
F3
10.0 Tf
%Resolving: [10 0]
<<
/Type /Font /SubType /Type1 /BaseFont /Palatino-Roman >>
endobj
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

GS>
```

Can anyone help me understand what the problem is with the pdf file I'm outputting?

Comment: At a first check: the length of the first stream `15660` seems incorrect, it probably should have been `15661`. After that, the `xref` offsets of the next objects are off by `1`. However, as fixing these numbers does not make it readable in Acrobat, there must be more. What is your source code for creating these items?

Comment: Ghostscript appears to be complaining about object 4 0, a type 1 font and object 7 0, also a type 1 font. You should set PDFSTOPONERROR as well as PDFDEBUG in this case, it will probably then give you a PostScript error which might be more useful to you. In fact, it gives an 'undefined' in run, which suggests there's use of an undefined procedure in there. Seems unlikely for a type 1 font. Note that current code (you should really update, 9.18 is 2 years old) does indeed complain that the length of object 5 (the first stream) is incorrect, as usr2564301 stated. Let me look at the PDF.

Comment: OK its a common one, you've mis-spelled /Subtype as /SubType.If I correct that (3 occurences), it works.

Comment: @usr2564301 The code is similar to the [code in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535765/whats-wrong-with-my-pdf-writer), but I'm not trying to share the latest version online until I get paid. :)

Comment: Additionally, the font dictionaries are incomplete, they miss the entries which are optional for the standard 14 fonts (and even not for them anymore in PDF 2).

Comment: And you don't refer to the fonts using a name object. Using name objects and fixing the "SubType" issue is enough to make Adobe Reader display text in your PDF. The PDF is not really valid but at least Adobe Reader can work with it.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for your help. I think you're talking about the `/` decoration  on font identifiers like `F1`. For the font dictionaries, do I need all the optional pieces or are there a few important ones I should add? I'm guessing `/Encoding` and `/Metrics` are important. Any others? I'm trying to avoid embedding the whole font for now, for simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of errors in the PDF. Depending on the PDF viewer in question it is required to fix a smaller or larger subset of them to allow displaying the PDF as intended.

#### page content streams

The contents of the page content streams look like this:

```
BT F1 10.0 Tf 30.0 750.0 Td (<< ) Tj ET BT F1 10.0 Tf 50.0 738.0 Td (/) Tj ET [...]
```

The error here is in the font selection instructions:

```
F1 10.0 Tf
```

The font name operand **F1** is not given as a PDF name object (recognizable by a leading slash) but as some generic literal usually reserved for instruction operators.

(As an aside, these content stream structures are unnecessarily bloated, most individual text objects draw merely one to three glyphs and have (always identical) text font selection instructions of their own. Not an error per se but completely unnecessary)

Furthermore, as already indicated by @usr2564301, the stream length appears to be off by 1.

#### font resources

The font resources each look like this:

```
<<
  /Type /Font 
  /SubType /Type1 
  /BaseFont /Palatino-Roman 
>>
```

First of all there is an issue in what is there: As already indicated by @KenS the correct spelling is **Subtype**, not **SubType**.

There is another issue in what is *not* there: So short font resource dictionaries up to PDF 1.7 were only allowed for standard 14 fonts and for PDF 2.0 aren't allowed at all anymore. As **Palatino-Roman** clearly is no standard 14 font, the resource is incomplete anyways.

According to Table 109 — Entries in a Type 1 font dictionary in ISO 32000-2,

- **Type**, **Subtype**, and **BaseFont** are universally *Required*,
- **FirstChar**, **LastChar**, **Widths**, and **FontDescriptor** are *Required but in PDF 1.0-1.7 Optional for the standard 14 fonts*,
- **Name** is *Required in PDF 1.0, Optional in PDF 1.1 through 1.7, Deprecated in PDF 2.0*, and
- **Encoding** and **ToUnicode** are universally *Optional*.

Depending on the PDF viewer you try requirements probably appear more relaxed but any PDF processor may justifiably reject your PDFs if you fail to meet the specification requirements.

#### cross references

@usr2564301 also mentions that many cross reference table entries (and also the reference to the start of the cross reference table itself) are off by 1.

They indeed don't point to the object number / **xref** literal but to the white space before. As only white spaces have to be ignored before the number / literal, many PDF processors won't notice.